# Traversing a Graph polynomial time

Tags: graphs, time-complexity

Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ and a starting vertex $v_1$.

The graphs edges is this

$\{(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3), (v_3, v_4)\}$

basically below

$(v_1) \to (v_2) \to (v_3) \to (v_4)$

Can we traverse this graph and record the path starting at $v_1$ in $O(|V|)$ time?

For example Making a list like $[(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3), (v_3, v_4)]$

I'm confused whether this takes $O(|V|^2)$ worst case time because the edges are in a set

Comment: How is the graph given to you? Also, in order to consider asymptotics, you should define a general problem.

Comment: $(v_1) \to (v_2) \to \dots \to (v_n)$. No other edges and we are given only the starting $(v_1)$.

Comment: Are the edges ordered?

Comment: Yes from $v_1$ to $v_n$

Comment: So it should take linear time.

Comment: O(|V| + |E|) or O(|V|) Is another confusion I have

Comment: They’re the same in your case.

Comment: `|V| = |E| + 1`, so `O(|V| + |E|)` is the same as `O(|E| + 1 + |E|)`, which is still just `O(|E|)`. The same transformation can be used to conclude `O(|V|)`, so they're equivalent.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, I think Tree Garen's question is, what if the edges were not ordered in the given set, would this still take linear time?

Comment: @J.Schmidt I asked them specifically about that, and they replied in the affirmative.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, hmm yes, let me state this differently. What if the given edges are indeed ordered from $(v_1,v_2)$ up to $(v_{n-1},v_n)$ but given in a set in a random order? For example as the set $[(v_2, v_3), (v_4, v_5), (v_3, v_4), (v_1, v_2)]$ for $n=5$?

Comment: You can either sort the edges or use a hash table. But if you’re interested in a different question, you should ask it.